# how to get dynamic color change based on values in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to plot a graph using high charts. I need to get colour changed based on the flag values .

I tried using this but I am getting only points are changed based on the flag, but I am  not getting the line coloured .

here is my code.

```
$(function () {
var getColor = {'g' : '#008000',
            'r' : '#FF0000',
            'b' : '#000000'};
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    }, series: [{
        name: 'London',
        data: [{y:3.9,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:4.2,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:5.7,flag:1,color:'#008000'},{y:8.5,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:11.9,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:15.2,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:17.0,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:16.6,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:14.2,flag:2,color:'#ff0000'},{y:10.3,flag:0,color:'#000000'},{y:6.6,flag:1,color:'#008000'},{y:4.8,flag:2,color:'#ff0000'}]
    }]
}/*,function(chart){
$.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

    if(data.flag == 0){
    console.log('green');
    color : getColor['g']}
    if(data.flag ==1){
    console.log('black');
    color : getColor['b']}
    if(data.flag == 2){
    console.log('red');
    color : getColor['r']}
    });

}*/);
 });
```

please help me out. need to get the colored line along with the point.. i m not getting where i m doing wrong, plzzzz help me.

Comment: you'll have to use color the same way you use flag, `data.color = someColor` instead of `color`

Comment: based on the flag oly i need to change the color . but there i  m getting oly points are colored but not line

Comment: Ouuu, sorry. but what colour do you want the line to be? If a green point is connected to a red point, what should be the colour of the line connecting them?

Comment: in high charts we have zones.. based on zones we ll get the color changed. my requirement is, when ever the flag 0,1,2 based on the flag the zone colors should change. in case flag==0 then i should get green color, if flag==1 den black and else red color.

Comment: then you need to define the zones array in the series object. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/).

Comment: this is my data....{y:3.9,flag:0,color:'#000000'} here u can c flag == 0 then i need to plot y value in the color black

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Multicolor series plugin](https://github.com/blacklabel/multicolor_series/), for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sz0esszz/11/

Simply change type of the series to `coloredline` and for each of the points set `segmentColor`, which defines line color between current point and next point.

Comment: when I hover over a point, the colour that I see is the default colour for the series. How can I display the point colour instead of the series colour?

Comment: Use [`marker.states.hover.fillColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.states.hover.fillColor). See (first point): http://jsfiddle.net/sz0esszz/13/

Comment: is there an inbuilt way to tell highcharts to use the point colour as fill colour, without having to define the marker object for each point in the series?

Comment: This is reported as bug in Highcharts [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1440). You can use workaround for that: http://jsfiddle.net/sz0esszz/14/

Comment: segmentColor cannot be sent dynamically??  like  this way is the correct way                                                                                           var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time                                        y=Math.round($scope.predictiveData[$scope.index1++].value), color='#000000',                                                             segmentColor = '#000000';                                        series2.addPoint([x, y],true, true);

Comment: It can be, you simply didn't set it, change: `series2.addPoint([x, y],true, true);` to `series2.addPoint({ x: x, y: y, segmentColor: segmentColor, color: color },true, true);`